# List index out of range depsite printing out the right ones

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to grab all the file connections in all the surface shaders in my scene.
However, I keep getting the following error even though it is printing out all the geo names:

```
# Error: list index out of range
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 6, in <module>
# IndexError: list index out of range #
```

I am using the names to reassign new shaders onto it, and sadly it is able to assign 1-2 onto the right mesh while others are not assigned at all.

This is the code that I am using to grab the names:

```
import pymel.core as pm
import maya.cmds as cmds
surShader = cmds.ls(type = 'surfaceShader')
for con in surShader:
    surShaderOut = cmds.listConnections('%s.outColor' % con)
    meshAssign = pm.listConnections(surShaderOut[1], type = "mesh")[0].longName()
    print meshAssign
```

Comment: either `surShaderOut` has no second element, or `pm.listConnections(surShaderOut[1], type = "mesh")` is an empty list. Debug it and find out =/

Comment: @AdamSmith  The output of the `surShaderOut` is as follows: `[u'RefRep_619_1138_1File', u'RefRep_619_1138_1SG']` and since I am taking the latter one, I am puzzled why would you say that the list will be empty. Before the start line of the error message, it is actually printing out all the name of the meshes

Comment: What happens if you print: pm.listConnections(surShaderOut[1], type = "mesh")

Comment: @yan because `[][0]` returns an `IndexError` much like your code does.

Comment: @OlympusMonds Plucking your code into mine, it sort of works but I need the long name of the mesh so that it can get 'read' by its next function

Comment: @AdamSmith Pardon my lack of knowledge but I do not really get what you mean :(

Comment: @yan my guess is that `pm.listConnection(surShaderOut[1], type='mesh')` returns an empty list. Therefore when you're trying to access the first element of that list, it throws an `IndexError`.

Comment: @yan I understand, but you have an error, so it needs to be debugged by deconstructing the commands one at a time. If `print pm.listConnection(surShaderOut[1], type='mesh')` results in `[]` or `None`, then we will know the listConnection function is not performing as expected. This is what @AdamSmith is trying to explain.

Comment: @OlympusMonds (worth noting: `None[0]` throws `TypeError`. It really does have to return an empty container. It could be a tuple though! :D)

Comment: @AdamSmith good point! Thanks.

Comment: @AdamSmith I tried `pm.listConnections(surShaderOut[1], type = "mesh")`, just running it, prints out all the elements where the output is `[nt.Transform(u'Ref3D_742_1')]`. Adding a [0] behind, also print out everything and the output is `Ref3D_742_1`. And running it with [] behind, gives off a syntax error